# Expected primary expression before ;

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to compile a C++ program (Compiler: GCC v4.1.2). The program is a simulation code which I cannot entirely post here for legal reasons. The code includes multiple header files which in turn include other standard C++ header files.

However, upon compilation

```
  g++ -c ABC.C -I/home/include...
```

I get the following errors:

```
/usr/include/assert.h: In function ‘void __assert_fail(const char*, const char*, unsigned int, const char*)’: 
/usr/include/assert.h:70: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token 
/usr/include/assert.h: At global scope: 
/usr/include/assert.h:70: error: declaration does not declare anything 
/usr/include/assert.h: In function ‘void __assert_perror_fail(int, const char*, unsigned int, const char*)’: 
/usr/include/assert.h:76: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token 
/usr/include/assert.h: At global scope: 
/usr/include/assert.h:76: error: declaration does not declare anything 
/usr/include/assert.h: In function ‘void __assert(const char*, const char*, int)’: 
/usr/include/assert.h:82: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token 
/usr/include/assert.h: At global scope: 
/usr/include/assert.h:82: error: declaration does not declare anything 
make: *** [create_SPH_IC.o] Error 1
```

According to the compiler, the error occurs in assert.h which is a standard header file.

I tried compiling the code without assert.h, the compiler gives me another set of errors declaring that I require assert.h for the simulation to run.

I looked at other questions in SO on 'expected primary-expression before token' error. However, I cannot modify the assert.h header file. Additionally, I wrote an another isolated code which uses assert.h and did not get this error. The simulation code also runs fine on other machines.
I am unable to trace the root of the problem any further. Can someone please guide me on how to diagnose this issue?

Please let me know what additional information is required.

Comment: i think u missing ',' or ';' and so on, check carefully before #include "assert"

Comment: Remove as many bits of your program as you can while making sure you continue to get the error. If you have a minimal program that gives you this error, it's probably already clear what the problem is, and if not, at least it's something you should then be able to include in your question.

Comment: Look at the definitions of the functions it's complaining about to see what they're trying to do (assert.h, lines 70, 76, 82).  You probably have a macro defined (via `#define`) that replaces the text in the header with something else, which results in the error.

Comment: maybe this could help: `g++ -E ABC.C -I/home/include... | grep -B 10 __assert_fail`